# How to sort by type - sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a query that sorts by `flag_color`, but I want it to priority by color:

This query right now returns:

```
SELECT   flag_color as color 
FROM     clinic_performance_flags 
GROUP BY clinic_user_id 
ORDER BY flag_color ASC
```

```
green
green
green
green
red
red
red
red
yellow
yellow
yellow
```

But I want to change the order, so the order becomes (`red` should always be first, `yellow` second and `green` third) example:

```
red
red
red
red
yellow
yellow
yellow
yellow
green
green
green
green
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT   flag_color as color 
FROM     clinic_performance_flags 
GROUP BY clinic_user_id 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN flag_color = 'red'    THEN 1
              WHEN flag_color = 'yellow' THEN 2
              WHEN flag_color = 'green'  THEN 3
                                         ELSE 4
         END, flag_color ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FIELD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function.

```
SELECT flag_color AS color 
FROM clinic_performance_flags 
GROUP BY clinic_user_id 
ORDER BY FIELD(flag_color ,'red','yellow','green'), flag_color ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CASE statement

```
SELECT   flag_color as color 
FROM     clinic_performance_flags 
GROUP BY clinic_user_id 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN flag_color = 'red' THEN 1
              WHEN flag_color = 'yellow' THEN 2
              WHEN flag_color = 'green' THEN 3
              ELSE 4 END
```